# Get User Name and Channel ID from YouTube API

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm using Android to access both the YouTube Analytics API and the YouTube Data API. Currently I have the app working that if I hard code in my personal Channel ID the app can retrieve information about my personal YouTube account.

However, I am using the Android AccountPicker to use GoogleAuthUtil so I have access to the user's email address. Is there a way to query YouTube to return their Channel ID using their email address?

Also is there a way to query YouTube to just receive back the user's User Name? I would like to greet them when in my app.

Thanks in advance!
~Jskuzma

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with "part=id & mine=true"

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

[Id](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#id) is the channel's ID.

You can get the video's title from the response under [snippet.title].
You can get the channel's title from the response under [snippet.channelTitle](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.title).

This title is what you are looking for to greet, but if you want to go deeper you can check if that [account is linked](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#status.isLinked) with Google+ and use [googleplususerid](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.googlePlusUserId) to retrieve more information via Google+ API.